# How to split a template into several file and include it later?

Tags: angular2-template

In a large APP, one of the components that access many services (Like a toolbox), the number of lines of HTML code within it increases.

How to separate the service-related templates (or a Tool) without using other components from the main template and store inside another template file, then it included into the main template(Like a parent and child template).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find the right way to do this. The only possible way was to use the component and share the variables by the service, so I put each tool in its component for that.